# how to change wifi password and ssid in blynk edgent

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

i recently changed my wifi ssid and password and i'm wondering how could i change the password i have already tried clearing the board with a flasher reuploading the code and nothing worked for it still tries to do it with the same credentials

```
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "Template"
#define BLYNK_DEVICE_NAME "name"
//#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "token"

int DeskLampButtonAttempts = 0;
int DoorLampButtonAttempts = 0;

uint8_t DeskPin = 16;
uint8_t DoorPin = 5;

uint8_t DeskButtonPin = 4;
uint8_t DoorButtonPin = 0;

#define BLYNK_FIRMWARE_VERSION        "0.1.0"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
//#define BLYNK_DEBUG

#define APP_DEBUG

// Uncomment your board, or configure a custom board in Settings.h
//#define USE_SPARKFUN_BLYNK_BOARD
#define USE_NODE_MCU_BOARD
//#define USE_WITTY_CLOUD_BOARD
//#define USE_WEMOS_D1_MINI

#include "BlynkEdgent.h"

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  digitalWrite(DeskPin, pinValue);
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  digitalWrite(DoorPin, pinValue);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  pinMode(DeskPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DoorPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(DeskButtonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(DoorButtonPin, INPUT);

  BlynkEdgent.begin();
}

void loop() {
  BlynkEdgent.run();
}
```

note: the properties template ETC. are set correctly just don't want them leaked

Answer (score 1):

When using BlynkEdgent, you need to reset the board through the phone app.
First reset the board by pressing the reset button for 10 seconds. It will create an AP with the name of the template, then the phone app can find it connect to it and prompt to provide WIFI credentials of your network.